# Rails: Loading custom class from lib folder in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've created a file as lib/services/my_service.rb.

```
# /lib/services/my_service.rb
class MyService
...
end
```

I want to use it in app/controllers/my_controller

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
     def method
          service = MyService.new()
     end
```

I'm getting an error that MyService is an uninitialized constant. I've tried to import it with

```
require '/lib/services/my_service.rb'
```

But I'm getting

```
cannot load such file -- /lib/services/my_service.rb
```

Edit: I have tried autoloading from application.rb using

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
```

But no dice. Still getting uninitialized constant MyController::MyService

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Ruby on Rails requires following certain naming conventions to support autoloading.

Rails can autoload a file located at `lib/services/my_service.rb` if the model/class structure was `Services::MyService`.

Change your `lib/services/my_service.rb` to:

```
module Services
  class MyService
    # ...
  end
end
```

And use that class like this in your controller:

```
service = Services::MyService.new
```

Please note that depending on your Ruby on Rails version, you might need to add the `lib` folder to the list of folders which are queried when looking for a file to autoload:

```
# add this line to your config/application.rb:
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
```

Read more about [autoloading](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#config-autoload-paths) in the Rails Guides.

Comment: This solved it without having to explicitly require. Thanks for that.

Comment: I had the same issue, but `Services::MyService.new` wasn't required after `application.rb` was updated and server was restarted. I was able to access my custom class with `MyService.new()` from the controller.

Answer (score 10):

You probably need to enable the autoload from the files in the `lib/` folder:

```
# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib"
```

If you prefer to do it "manually", then you can only require such file in the same file:

```
# config/application.rb
require './lib/my_service'
```

After this a restart is necessary.

Comment: Tried that already to autoload it. Still getting uninitialized constant MyController::MyService

Comment: Try then with `require './lib/my_service'` and restarting your server.

Comment: Seems like the dot at the beginning of the require statement fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there is a setting in config/application.rb in which you can specify directories that contain files you want autoloaded.

From application.rb:

```
# Custom directories with classes and modules you want to be autoloadable.
# config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/extras)
```

or

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

rails 3

```
Dir["lib/**/*.rb"].each do |path|
  require_dependency path
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your application.rb

```
config.eager_load_paths << Rails.root.join('lib/services')
```