# Proper Way to Instantiate Subclass Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I've got 3 classes with the Parent being `Messenger` like so:

```
class Messenger
    #methods defined here:
end

class Email < Messenger
    #send email and other email related stuff
end

class Sms < Messenger
    #send text messages and other related stuff
end
```

In my Rails controller I want to either instantiate a new email or sms object and send a message via the appropriate messaging channel. How do I need to setup my require statements? I'm mainly familiar with Java so I'd usually just import the classes but I wasn't sure of the correct Ruby way of doing this.

I had previously put these three lines at the top of my controller:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/classes/email.rb"
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/classes/sms.rb" 
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/classes/messenger.rb"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are these files located? If they are under `app`, then you shouldn't need to `require` them as they will be autoloaded.

Comment: Autoload but it is required to respect naming convention, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47119792/5239030)

Comment: It would be very unusual for a file in a rails project *not* to contain a class, or a module. So putting classes into a folder named `lib/classes` is almost certainly a bad design! What do these classes do? Are they plain old ruby objects, or does `Messenger` subclass 
 e.g. `ActiveRecord::Base`? At the very least, if there's really no better place to put these files, you could do something like: `lib/messengers/{base,sms,email}.rb`. Then inside, `module Messenger; class Sms < Base; ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you should consider putting these in a directory named `messengers` under `app`, like:

```
- app
  |- messengers
     |- messenger_base.rb
     |- email_messenger.rb
     |- sms_messenger.rb
```

And then define your classes like:

```
class MessengerBase
  #methods defined here:
end

class EmailMessenger < MessengerBase
  #send email and other email related stuff
end

class SmsMessenger < MessengerBase
  #send text messages and other related stuff
end
```

IMO, a name like `EmailMessenger` is clearer than just `Email`. With this, autoloading should work fine and no need for `require` statements.